# Multiple font markers in shapefiles in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, cartography, style, markers, land-survey

I'm making a UK phase 1 vegetation survey map and require to show the dominant plant species in a given polygon.  In phase 1 these are shown as 2- or 3-letter codes e g Ri, Cys.  These codes need to be located very precisely and as far as I can see, the various labelling options in QGIS do not allow sufficient precision.  I am therefore trying to create point shapefiles for each dominant plant species.  Is there a way of using multiple letters in the "font marker" symbol layer type?

Answer (score 6):

You can add another symbol layer:

[image: Symbol layer]

Select the new symbol layer, add your letter/symbol and alter the **Offset X,Y**, so in your case it would just be the **X**.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You do not need to use symbols because labels are more efficient (and easy to use).

You can set the label position exactly where you want it.

You first create a column in your file with x coord and one with y, then set them (as you see in the image):

[image]

and then after that, you can move the label (using the tool "Move label").

Comment: Ahh, you learn something new everyday :)

Answer (score 1):

For those of you here for the multiple font markers. Since QGIS version 3.8 you can add them.

> While QGIS has long offered support for rendering points using font-based character markers, we’ve enhanced this functionality in 3.8 and now offer the ability to render multi-character strings! And since we’re always aiming to make the QGIS application interface as user-friendly and pleasant to use as possible, we also took the opportunity to tweak the UI for font markers and squash a number of frustrating GUI issues which previous versions suffered from.
> [image]